# When using AlivePDF library in Flex the beginFill method sets font colour rather than background colour

Tags: apache-flex, flex3, alivepdf

Code sample:

```
var headerRowBackground:RGBColor = new RGBColor(0);
headerRowBackground.b = 58;
headerRowBackground.g = 28;
headerRowBackground.r = 255;
printPDF.beginFill(headerRowBackground);
printPDF.addCell(30, 20, "Room");
```

The word "Room" is in red, as is the rest of the text in the PDF. I actually want to make the cell background colour red. Anybody know why this doesn't work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [documentation](http://alivepdf.bytearray.org/alivepdf-asdoc/org/alivepdf/pdf/PDF.html#addCell%28%29) is wrong, the fill parameter is described as "Link can be internal to do document level navigation (InternalLink) or external (HTTPLink)".

The code to get this working is:

```
printPDF.beginFill(new RGBColor(0xFF0718));
printPDF.textStyle(new RGBColor(0x000000));
printPDF.addCell(30, 10, "Room", 0, 0, Align.LEFT, 1);
```

A couple of things about the code:

1. The fill parameter should be 0 or 1
   rather than the fill value. It just
   either switches on or off the fill
   value previously set.
2. The text style
       should be set too otherwise the text
       and background will use the same
       colour

Answer (score 0):

You should look [at the API](http://alivepdf.bytearray.org/alivepdf-asdoc/org/alivepdf/pdf/PDF.html#addCell%28%29) more:

```
printPDF.addCell(30, 20, 'Room', 0, 0, '1', 0xFF0000);
```